# Adding events dynamically

Tags: windows, winforms, events, dynamic, picturebox

I have n picture boxes.  They should perform the following events dynamically:

```
private void pictureBoxMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (sender is PictureBox)
    {
        ((PictureBox)sender).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }
}

private void pictureBoxMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is PictureBox)
    {
        ((PictureBox)sender).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    }
}

private void MainMaster_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var control in Controls)
    {
        if (sender is PictureBox)
        {
            PictureBox pb=new PictureBox();
            pb.Name = sender.ToString();
            pb.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBoxMouseHover);
            pb.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBoxMouseHover);
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't find what wrong with this; please help me.

Answer (score 2):

[dbaseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001985/dbaseman) is right, you used wrong variable when iterating through controls.

But if you want to add this behavior to all picture boxes, then better solution is to create custom picture box, and simply place it on your form:

```
public class MyPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseHover(EventArgs e)
    {
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        base.OnMouseHover(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    }
}
```

Create this class, compile app and drag these custom picture boxes from toolbox to your form. They all will display border when mouse hover over picture box.

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake is here:

```
foreach (var control in Controls)
{
    if (sender is PictureBox)
```

**Sender** in this case will be the window.  I think you intended **control**.

```
foreach (var control in Controls)
{
    if (control is PictureBox)
```